change the appearance of the \equation
I use this code to change the appearance of the equation, but it is full of errors even if at the end it gives a result, please help me to correct it. Thank you .
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\let\oldequation\equation
\let\endoldequation\endequation
\RenewEnviron{equation}{\everymath{\displaystyle}
\everydisplay{\displaystyle}
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\centering
    \fcolorbox{white}{lightgray!30}{
      \begin{oldequation}\nonumber 
        \BODY 
      \end{oldequation}
    }
  \end{minipage}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
n!\underset{n\rightarrow +\infty }{\sim }\left( \frac{n}{e}\right) ^{n}.%
\sqrt{2\pi n}
\end{equation}%
\bigskip

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}


You cannot just wrap \fcolorbox around equation, that does not work even without the redefinition. Perhaps you should start by explaining what the endgoal is? THen perhaps others can come up with better solutions.

I guess you want to show the equation with a gray background.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\NewEnvironmentCopy{oldequation}{equation}
\NewEnvironmentCopy{oldequation*}{equation*}
\RenewDocumentEnvironment{equation}{b}{%
  \everymath{\displaystyle}%
  \everydisplay{\displaystyle}%
  \begin{oldequation}
  \fcolorbox{white}{lightgray!30}{$#1$}%
  \end{oldequation}
}{\ignorespacesafterend}
\RenewDocumentEnvironment{equation*}{b}{%
  \everymath{\displaystyle}%
  \everydisplay{\displaystyle}%
  \begin{oldequation*}
  \fcolorbox{white}{lightgray!30}{$#1$}%
  \end{oldequation*}
}{\ignorespacesafterend}


\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-4]
\begin{equation}
n!\underset{n\rightarrow +\infty }{\sim }\left( \frac{n}{e}\right) ^{n}\cdot\sqrt{2\pi n}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[2][1-4]
\begin{equation*}
n!\underset{n\rightarrow +\infty }{\sim }\left( \frac{n}{e}\right) ^{n}\cdot
\sqrt{2\pi n}
\end{equation*}
\lipsum[3][1-4]

\end{document}

Note that the period is never used as a multiplication symbol.

For rounded corners you can use tcolorbox.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcbox{\eqbox}{colback=lightgray!30,boxrule=0pt,box align=base}

\NewEnvironmentCopy{oldequation}{equation}
\NewEnvironmentCopy{oldequation*}{equation*}
\RenewDocumentEnvironment{equation}{b}{%
  \begin{oldequation}
  \mbox{\eqbox{$\displaystyle#1$}}
  \end{oldequation}
}{\ignorespacesafterend}
\RenewDocumentEnvironment{equation*}{b}{%
  \begin{oldequation*}
  \mbox{\eqbox{$\displaystyle#1$}}
  \end{oldequation*}
}{\ignorespacesafterend}


\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-4]
\begin{equation}
n!\underset{n\rightarrow +\infty }{\sim }\left( \frac{n}{e}\right) ^{n}\cdot\sqrt{2\pi n}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[2][1-4]
\begin{equation*}
n!\underset{n\rightarrow +\infty }{\sim }\left( \frac{n}{e}\right) ^{n}\cdot
\sqrt{2\pi n}
\end{equation*}
\lipsum[3][1-4]

\end{document}



Thank you very much, it's a good job, I wonder if it's possible to make the corners round

@M.La For that you need tcolorbox.

Sorry I couldn't use it. Can you help me please

@M.La I added an example. Look in the manual to modify it.

Thank you very much,
